# My stacked svg images flicker when displayed

Tags: javascript, image, html, flicker

I have up to 6 svg images stacked to create an interactive image for the user. (Stacked using embed tags within a div).

At the moment, each image is drawing itself, causing a flicker as the bottom image is drawn then the top images.

I have preloaded the images in CSS

```
#element_01 {
    background: url(img/model/model.png) no-repeat;
    display: none;
    }
```

and I have tried & succeeded in hiding the div element, then displaying it.

```
    '<div class="modelImage" style="visibility:hidden">'+
    '<embed id="myTop"  src="img/model/top.svg"     onload="this.getSVGDocument().onclick = function(event){control.colorClothes(0);};"     title="top"     type="image/svg+xml" width="325" height="500">'+
```

followed by

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".modelImage")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    });
```

an alert confirms this works, but without the alert the images still write themselves sequentially resulting in a flicker. Frustratingly the image prints great when I have the alert!

Comment: What's going on with your last code block? Are you not familiar with jQuery's `ready` event??

Comment: @Shmiddty :) no, ta for that, I've googled & amended the code. But I've still got the original issue.

Comment: in the ready event, you can just write `$(".modelImage").show();`. That will replace all of that code.

Comment: in fact, the entire third block could be simplified to: `$(function(){$(".modelImage").show();});`

Comment: @Schmiddty I can't get the jQuery show() to work, but thanks to your pointer I've trimmed the third code block quite a bit. Ta. It works like this as well as it did before, but I still have the original problem.